# Disable or lock zoom in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, zoom

Is it possible to disable or lock the zoom feature in Notepad++?

I'm doing a lot of copying and pasting, and the zoom level keeps changing on me.  It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Should be migrated to Superuser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The zooming is happening (I think) because I have a cheap Microsoft mouse, and the scroll wheel sometimes doesn't roll all the way to the next tick when I stop scrolling. Then, later, when I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste the wheel snaps into place, thus causing what appears to be a spontaneous zoom.

Unfortunately, because this problem is occurring on my PC at work, I don't have the option of replacing the mouse, which would be my normal solution. So, what I would like to do, if possible, is disable or lock the zoom feature on Notepad++.

Comment: I ended up getting a better mouse.

Comment: IMHO, You shouldn't accept your own answer with so many answers that really do answer the question you asked

Comment: Some computer mice have a mode that either makes the wheel freewheeling or "clicking" (like in [cmroanirgo's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/26015/disable-or-lock-zoom-in-notepad/225325#225325)).

Answer (score 8):

Previously, I "Seriously ... cannot imagine a scenario where you're accidentally zooming." The hot keys involve Control-Mousewheel, or Control-Keypad-plus-or-minus. (If you'll excuse the description). These aren't near or similar to Control-C and Control-V.  So you must be holding the control key while meaning to scroll in the document.

It was just pointed out to me that the trackpad might also be an issue (Jim himself said it was his mouse and he changed his mouse for resolving this). If it's the trackpad then you'd have to try to find a palm rejection sensitivity setting to tweak, which might not be available, or try remapping the zoom shortcuts, or try the plugin from Stan which disables zooming (I like that option a lot).

Anyway, it's been a while since I used it, but I'm told you can edit the shortcuts in the `settings > shortcut mapper`.

Comment: No, you can edit NPP shortcuts now, going to `Settings > Shortcut mapper`.

Comment: @Igoru thanks, I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Some mouse wheels are a bit finicky and can scroll when you aren't touching the wheel (eg. you stopped turning just before the next skip, and a minute later it is jostled passed it). If you're hold control at the time, you zoom. This happens to me all the time.

Comment: @Strilanc I never encountered this but it sounds aggravating. Consider buying another mouse. I'm happy with my http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/428/3287&hub=1&cl=us,en

Comment: dlamblin, it happens when you Ctrl+C and then start scrolling a split second before you let go of Ctrl. Happens to me from time to time -- it just depends on the user.

Comment: @nbolton Yes, I get that. For me that's like when you get a new keyboard and the shift key is smaller or the home key moved. It's very annoying for a while. Then you adjust. But you can see Jim Fell's problem was the notches on his scrollwheel.

Comment: @dlamblin Sure thing, you clearly know best.

Comment: @dlamblin I am accidentally resizing notepad++ all the time when coding on my laptop with a mouse pad.  If I am using Ctrl with other keys and my palm swipes the scrolling edge of my mouse pad, the program gets zoomed beyond recognition.  It is all too easy to do; very frustrating.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's been a very long time since I wrote this, but yeah, I could see the trackpad triggering a scroll while holding a modifier key. I mean there's all kinds of trackpads out there and some are better at palm rejection than others. Also I wouldn't disable trackpad scrolling as you'd likely use it often, so, if this can be remapped... I guess that would be one way.

Comment: I have a mouse with free heavy wheel for fast scrolling, so I scroll long page, and got to the top, I don't know mouse while it still spinning, so I hit Ctrl to copy and boom zoom in, so is `"Seriously ... cannot imagine a scenario where you're accidentally zooming."` a sarcasm?

Comment: @PawelCioch it happens to me and others too; I maybe didn't edit this answer best, but first I had said that 13 years ago. Then 8 years ago I updated it to say what I had said, so I'm not hiding it, and acknowledge there's multiple ways this might happen accidentally that you can't retrain, and advise that there's setting that help avoid it (that were not there 13 years ago). I have used a mouse like you describe, but have a toggle between free-scroll and notched scroll. The MX Master 3 no longer has a toggle and decides on its own when to use notches and when to free-wheel. It's a downside.

Answer (score 6):

To disable mouse zooming, I wrote [a small plugin for Notepad++](https://github.com/StanDog/npp-zoomdisabler) which does it.

Also, there is a 64-bit version of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, that helped somewhat (better than answers to the effect of "buy a new mouse", at least). What I really want, though, is a way to remap the hotkeys - they aren't in the Shortcut Mapping menu, and I don't have a numeric keypad on my computer.

Comment: @BibaswannBandyopadhyay I'm glad that it helped you. :-)

Comment: this is the best and easy. Thanks! why repo is archived? not envisioning changes for new n++ versions?

Comment: @PawelCioch I'm no longer maintaining the repository due to missing time and interest. The plugin should however still work in current NPP versions, I think. The compiled binaries and the sourecode are still available. Also, someone wrote me that they will integrate this functionality in their own plugin, so you might find it there. In case you want to implement it yourself: Just catch the message `SCN_ZOOM` and send the message `SCI_SETZOOM` with a fixed value which represents the zoom value in the scintilla window. That's basically all the plugin does.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have that issue.  The only way it zooms is if you use CTRL-MouseWheel, or by CTRL-KP+ or CTRL-KP-.  Most likely, you are trying to scroll the document when you still have CTRL held down (or active via StickyKeys.)

Best recommendation is to use CTRL-KP/ to reset the zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I have a logitech mouse and love it. It has a mousewheel that doesn't 'click' as you scroll, but operates more like a flywheel... So, when I scroll somewhere and then start using the keyboard (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), suddenly I've zoomed. Most annoying ;)

Changing shortcuts isn't the issue here. It's the way we use an editor and it's not really the mouse's problem.

PS: I can do a 'hard' center click on my mouse and it changes it from 'flywheel mode' to 'click mode' and back. It is the only workaround I have...and Notepad++ is the only program I need to do this with.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not necessary that you zoom accidentally, the problem is that some plugins revert to default zoom level. I would like to have a way to change default zoom level, or lock it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful reference on the topic?

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14280/disable-ctrl-mousewheel-zooming